# Rounding zero decimal in java

Tags: java, decimal, rounding, decimalformat

What's the proper way to round a decimal in 2 digits but as zero.
i.e if the number is 561.82 to be rounded as 562.00 ?

Comment: As a value 562 == 562.00 == 562.0000, the only difference is how the number has been formatted as a String.  First you round it, and then you format it how you want (sometimes in one step).  Note: it makes no sense to add `.00` if these digits are not accurate.

Comment: Definitely not "proper" to show `.00` at the end if you round to full integral values ...